# Do until Onkey{RIGHT}

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I want to loop the below action until I press the `{DOWN}`, but the Private Sub doesn't seem to be 100% right, and so the code just loops forever.

```
Public pressdown As Boolean

Sub DemoOnKey()
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "moveright"
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "moveleft"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "movedown"
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "moveup"

End Sub

Sub moveright()
  Do Until pressdown    
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Selection.Offset(0, 1)
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents

    DoEvents
  Loop

  If pressdown = True Then  
    Call movedown 'Calls similar macro to moveright, but to movedown, hehe  
  End If     
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyPress(Key As Integer)
  Const down = "{DOWN}"
  If Application.OnKey = down Then pressdown = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have `pressdown` declared as a global variable somewhere?

Comment: You have pressdown set to true when {DOWN} is pressed, not {RIGHT}

Comment: @Rdster, That was a typo, i actually meant to type {DOWN}. 
@Comintern do you mean like `Public pressdown As Range`?
I did it now and the macro resulted on an error on `Do Until pressdown`

Comment: You clearly are using pressdown as a Boolean, declare it as such.

Comment: A general comment - I've found that `SendKeys` can be pretty unwieldy - especially if you take focus off of Excel.  With that in mind, consider how you know *when* you want to press `RIGHT`. Perhaps there's another trigger that you could use instead of the key press?

Comment: To be honest I'm fairly new to vba and for training i decided to try and program a "Snake Game" from scratch, and this was a way i found to move through the sheet!

Comment: So...in order to learn VBA, you decided to use it in a way that is not even close to its normal use?  Sounds counter productive to me.  Wouldn't it have been better to learn it how it would actually be used?

Comment: Pretty much. I have a few other "serious" projects as well, this one is for fun and learning.

Comment: Do you in fact have a form, or are you trying to use this code in a sheet? (In any case the contents of `Form_KeyPress` will not compile.)

Comment: @Gserg please see my edit. I put everything on a module and for the code to start running i have to Run the macro `DemoOnKey`. Then i can Press `{RIGHT}` and the Macro starts looping. But it doesn't stop when i press `{DOWN}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `Form_KeyPress(Key As Integer)` in any random place. It's an event handler that must be in a user form. If it was there, you would get a compile time error because you can't do `If Application.OnKey = down`, whatever that means. You are getting away with it because this sub is never entered and therefore is never compiled.

Having that said, your approach is wrong.
Have a loop that moves the snake in the set direction, and have four key handlers that change this set direction.

Also note that a direct loop is not a good approach because it causes problems in Excel key presses handling. I would advise you use `OnTime` for the main loop:

```
private move_where as string

Sub DemoOnKey()
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "moveright"
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "moveleft"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "movedown"
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "moveup"
End Sub

private Sub moveright()
  move_where = "right"
end sub
private Sub moveleft()
  move_where = "left"
end sub
private Sub movedown()
  move_where = "down"
end sub
private Sub moveup()
  move_where = "up"
end sub


Sub move()
    select case move_where
    case "right"
      ' Move right here
    case "left"
      ' Move left here
    case "down"
      ' Move down here
    case "up"
      ' Move up here
    end select

    Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "move"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. So, i edited it for the following, for example:

   
    `Case "right"
      
    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=Selection.Offset(0, 1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents`

And tried moving, nothing happened.
Then i tried executing the macro `DemoOnKey` and it says "Member identifier already exists in object module from which this object module derives". On `Sub move()`

Comment: @Serveira You first execute `DemoOnKey`, then run `move` and go to the sheet to play. If it complains about members check that you do not have two procedures with same name. Also note I changed the code because a simple loop causes different problems if different Excel versions.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try! I see I still have a lot to learn. Thanks for making this code clearer.